# Why would 'groups' and 'groups [myname]' give different results?

Tags: permissions, user-management, groups

I am have trouble getting docker to work, and I suspect it has to do with permissions and membership of the 'docker' group.
I have run the command to add myself to the docker group

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

but it is still not working. I note that I get different results for `groups` and `groups [myname]`

```
$ groups
[myname] adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare

$ groups [myname]
[myname] : [myname] adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare docker
```

why would this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the case if you have modified your account (adding yourself to a group) and **not** logged out and back in.

To fix your situation, relogin to your session.  You can, but do not need to reboot.

Comment: I'm marking this as correct, but should note that log out then log in, did not work for me. Reboot did work.

Comment: @ChechyLevas I'll try that on one of my virtual machines, and update as required.  Thanks for letting me know!